# VBA Populating Combobox With Alternative Text

Tags: vba, combobox, ms-word

New to VBA so please forgive what may seem a simple question.

Using MS Word I have produced a simple form. I have a ComboBox that is populated via an array. This works fine. What I am trying to achieve is when an option is selected in this ComboBox, an alternative text entry is actually placed into the document at a Bookmark named *Advice*.

I am using Bookmarks as placemarkers in the Word document. At the moment the value already defined in the ComboBox is being place in the document, instead of the alternative.

Here is my code.

```
    Dim myArray1() As String
  'Use Split function to return a zero based one dimensional array
  myArray1 = Split("advice for option one|advice for option two|" _
             & "advice for option three", "|")
  'Use List method to populate listbox
  ComboBox2.List = myArray1 
  Exit Sub
  
  If ComboBox2.List = "advice for option one" Then
        Advice.Text = "This piece of text for option one. It's much longer than that in the DropBox, but it is what is needed."
        
    ElseIf ComboBox2.List = "advice for option two" Then
        Advice.Text = "This piece of text for option two. It's much longer than that in the DropBox, but it is what is needed."
        
    ElseIf ComboBox2.List = "advice for option three" Then
        Advice.Text = "This piece of text for option three. It's much longer than that in the DropBox, but it is what is needed."
        
    Else
        Advice.Text = ""
        
    End If
  
lbl_Exit:
  Exit Sub
End Sub
```

I'm sure I'm doing something really silly that is stopping this from working.

Thanks!

Sorry, I've just realised that I had missed the key part. Unsurprisingly this still doesn't work.

I've provided the rest of it and included your suggestion.

```
Private Sub CancelBut_Click()
UserForm.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub EnterBut_Click()
Dim number As Range
Set number = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("number").Range
number.Text = Me.TextBox1.Value
Dim Name As Range
Set Name = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Name").Range
Name.Text = Me.TextBox2.Value
Dim Name1 As Range
Set Name1 = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Name1").Range
Name1.Text = Me.TextBox2.Value
Dim Address As Range
Set Address = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Address").Range
Address.Text = Me.TextBox3.Value
Dim ReportDate As Range
Set ReportDate = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("ReportDate").Range
ReportDate.Text = Me.TextBox4.Value
Dim Location As Range
Set Location = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Location").Range
Location.Text = Me.TextBox5.Value
Dim Reason As Range
Set Reason = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Reason").Range
Reason.Text = Me.ComboBox1.Value
Dim Advice As Range
Set Advice = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Advice").Range
Advice.Text = Me.ComboBox2.Value
Dim Office As Range
Set Office = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Office").Range
Office.Text = Me.TextBox6.Value
Me.Repaint
UserForm.Hide
End Sub

Private Sub ToggleButton1_Click()
If ToggleButton1.Value = True Then
ComboBox2.Visible = True
Else
ComboBox2.Visible = False
End If
End Sub

Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim myArray() As String
  'Use Split function to return a zero based one dimensional array
  myArray = Split("problem1|problem2|problem3|problem4|" _
             & "problem5|problem6|problem7|problem8|problem9|" _
             & "problem10|problem11|problem12|problem13|problem14", "|")
  'Use List method to populate listbox
  ComboBox1.List = myArray
 
Dim myArray1() As String
  'Use Split function to return a zero based one dimensional array
  myArray1 = Split("advice for option one|advice for option two|" _
             & "advice for option three", "|")
  'Use List method to populate listbox
  ComboBox2.List = myArray1
  
  End Sub
  
  Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    Dim Advice As Range
    
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("Advice") = True Then
        Set Advice = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Advice").Range
        
        Select Case ComboBox2.Value
            Case "advice for option one":
                Advice.Text = "This piece of text for option one."
            Case "advice for option two":
                Advice.Text = "This piece of text for option two."
            Case "advice for option three":
                Advice.Text = "This piece of text for option three."
        End Select
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "Advice", Advice
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: You haven't shown the context in which the code is run. What's the sub, and how is it getting called? And you haven't what type of object the Advice variable is or how it got set. That's relevant info.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shown the context in which the code is run. What's the sub, and how is it getting called? And you haven't what type of object the Advice variable is or how it got set. Your code seems to be setting the combo items and trying to act on a combo selection in the same sub. That won't work.

You should create an event procedure within the form to populate the combo when the dialog is initialized.

```vb
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()
Dim myArray1() As String
  'Use Split function to return a zero based one dimensional array
  myArray1 = Split("advice for option one|advice for option two|" _
             & "advice for option three", "|")
  'Use List method to populate listbox
  ComboBox1.List = myArray1
End Sub
```

The have another event procedure within the form for a combo change event:

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim Advice As Range
    
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("advice") = True Then
        Set Advice = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("advice").Range
        
        Select Case ComboBox1.Value
            Case "advice for option one":
                Advice.Text = "This piece of text for option one."
            Case "advice for option two":
                Advice.Text = "This piece of text for option one."
            Case "advice for option three":
                Advice.Text = "This piece of text for option one."
        End Select
    End If
End Sub
```

This will replace the bookmark placeholder text with the indicated text. Note: the replacement will get rid of the bookmark as well, so it will only work once unless you reset the bookmark. If you want the bookmark to remain, you need to recreate it. The range object hasn't changed, so you can use that to create the new bookmark:

```vb
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    Dim Advice As Range
    
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("advice") = True Then
        Set Advice = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("advice").Range
        
        Select Case ComboBox1.Value
            Case "advice for option one":
                Advice.Text = "This piece of text for option one."
            Case "advice for option two":
                Advice.Text = "This piece of text for option two."
            Case "advice for option three":
                Advice.Text = "This piece of text for option three."
        End Select
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Add "advice", Advice
    End If
End Sub
```

So now, after you select an option in the combo box, the text in the doc will be updated, and the bookmark will be reset to the new text. So, you can make a different choice, and the text will be updated again.

Comment: I've realised that I hadn't provided enough code / information. The original post has been updated as the answer didn't work.

Comment: You added more code but didn't explain _how specifically_ it's not working. Have you tried setting any breakpoints and stepping through? If you set a breakpoint inside ComboBox2_Change(), then it should break whenever you make a different selection in the combo box.

Comment: Brand new to VBA so I'm still trying to learn. At the moment the problem is still the same in that the text in the combobox is still being added at the Bookmark in the word document. It is still not substituting the "alternate" text.

Answer (score 0):

You are over writing the text at the bookmark with the following code which is probably run when the form is closed.

```
Private Sub EnterBut_Click()
    ...
    Set Advice = ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("Advice").Range
    Advice.Text = Me.ComboBox2.Value
    ...
End Sub
```

Comment: Code still failing as shown between the asterisks.

Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    Dim Advice As Range
    If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("Advice") = True Then        
        Select Case ComboBox2.Value
            Case "advice for option one":
                ***Advice.Text = "This piece of text for option one."***
            Case "advice for option two":
                Advice.Text = "This piece of text for option two."
            Case "advice for option three":
                Advice.Text = "This piece of text for option three."
        End Select
    End If
End Sub

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
Dim Advice As Range

If ActiveDocument.Bookmarks.Exists("Advice") = True Then
            
    Select Case ComboBox2.Value
        Case "advice for option one":
            ***Advice.Text = "This piece of text for option one."***
        Case "advice for option two":
            Advice.Text = "This piece of text for option two."
        Case "advice for option three":
            Advice.Text = "This piece of text for option three."
    End Select
    
End If
```

End Sub

Comment: Right, this makes sense. I'd actually seen that I'd declared the "Advice" variable twice. Removing it from the top part of the code where the rest are set solved the problem.

Comment: Just as another follow on - how much "text" could I sensibly add to the code to embellish the "Advice"? Or is it better to "import" in some way? If the latter, then is there somewhere that can be highlighted to me so that I can do this?

Comment: 1) What is the maximum statement length?
2) How does one go about storing the value in the MS Word document?

I'm hoping that when an option is selected via the ComboBox, this will populate my document with anything from a couple of sentences up to say an A4 sheet's worth.

Comment: If you are doing this properly you will have created a template (dotm) for your document to hold the code, styles etc. If that is the case you can store the various texts as Quick Parts.

Comment: I have indeed created and added the VBA and saved it in a (dotm) document. Can I or indeed, how do I initiate a selected Quick Part in the VBA coding that I have shown on this forum? i.e. selecting a Quick Part via the ComboBox

Comment: SO is not a forum and this question is now straying far off topic. I suggest you try Google and Bing to learn more about the topic and record macros to give you syntax. Unless things have changed Quick Parts/Building Blocks are not available on macOS.

Comment: Understood! I'll have a bit of a Google about and see what I can find. Thanks to all for their input.